# throttle http requests in a javascript forEach

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I have code that is making an HTTP request in a `forEach` iteration.  The problem is, all of the HTTP requests are firing off at once.

```
const main = async () => {
    
    items.forEach(async (i: Item) => {
        const response = await fetch(/* code and stuff */)
    });
}

main()
```

I am flooding the server with requests in this particular case as all items are subsequently firing off.

Is there a way to make the fetch synchronous in this case, so that only one is being sent to the URL behind `fetch()` at a time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Might be asking the wrong question.  Request throttling and load balancing are usually handled by the web server. Using sync or async/await on the client for throttling will not scale because the clients are all operating async of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the items in a `for` loop and `await` each `fetch` before processing the following one.

```
const main = async () => {
    
    for (let item of items) {
      await fetch("url with item")
    }
}

main()
```

If you want a to chunk "a few" items at once, check [this article](https://dev.to/_hariti/parallel-promise-execution-beyound-promiseall-33ik) I wrote a while back